# How do I get and use a value from another sheet in Google Docs?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google docs sheet that has 5 sheets.  The first has all of the data and the other 4 are specific only to a particular name.  The header fields are name, fruit, entree, salad dressing, dessert, and day.  One of the names on the sheet is Jeremy.  He has 7 different records, obviously and so do the other 3 people on the sheet.  What I want to be able to do is look on Jeremy's sheet and and pull the dessert (Sheet 1 Column E) for a specific day (let's say Monday currently).  I'll have 7 rows, so the value needs to change, but I want to look on the Overview Sheet and find the 1 dessert that has Jeremy listed for that specific day.

Comment: can you share a sample sheet with the 'dummy' data?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VoAC-20ZxnHq-xPHwAO7ZcdKvfoiQAtBd8JBjEWp1WY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

For each sheet you can add a filter function starting in row two such as :

```
=filter(Overview!A:F,Overview!A:A="Jeremy")
```

you can add multiple filter flags however you like for your conditions:

```
=filter(Overview!A:F,Overview!A:A="Jeremy",Overview!F:F="Wednesday")
```

or

```
=filter(Overview!E:E,Overview!A:A="Jeremy",Overview!F:F="Wednesday")
```

or you can pull in his name and the specified columns and split:

```
=split(filter(Overview!A:A&","&Overview!E:E,Overview!A:A="Jeremy",Overview!F:F="Wednesday"),",")
```

Comment: This gives me every column and every row for Jeremy.  I'm looking for a way to only get 1 cell by looking for Jeremy's dinner on Monday, for example.

Comment: quick question before i answer that - how do you prefer to choose the day and meal? do you want a drop down? or?

Comment: @GJJ see above comment

Comment: For example, on the Jeremy tab A2, I want to use a formula to get the fruit for Jeremy on Monday.

Comment: do you want it to change according to which day is currently is when you are on the sheet? or do you want a dropdown to choose to see "meal type" you want and "day of the week you want"

Comment: No I don't need a dropdown.  If I have the formula, I can grab the necessary cell for the day, person, and meal